# Symbolic Link as a real file

Tags: linux, unix

I am new to Linx.

I have a file oops.c  in   `/home/tuna/objects`   directory.

I wanted to create a symbolic link for above file in `/home/tuna/myfolder` .

I tried  `cd /home/tuna/myfolde $:  ln -s /home/tuna/objects/oops.c oops.c`

And when i open the link, its empty. I want to have the link same as original file .

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest form of `ln` is this to create a symlink:

```
cd /home/tuna/myfolder
ln -s /home/tuna/objects/oops.c
cat oops.c     # This will print the file
```

What exactly do you mean when you say "when I look it is empty"?

An extract from `ln`'s man page, just to clarify things:

```
   ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
   ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
```

Your original code is the 3rd form which tries to create a symlink to `/home/tune/objects/oops.c` in the folder `oops.c`.
You should use the 2nd form which creates a symlink called `oops.c` in the current folder, pointing to `home/tuna/objects/oops.c`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do `ls` to see if it is correctly linked to the file.

Type `ls -l` and see the list of files in your `/home/tuna/myfolder` directory.
You should see something like:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 tuna None xx Sep 16 12:00 oops.c -> /home/tuna/objects/oops.c`

if you don't see something like this, you may want to try again with full path.
like:

`ln -s /home/tuna/objects/oops.c /home/tuna/myfolder/oops.c`

Answer (score 1):

```
ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink
```

so in your case

```
ln -s /home/tuna/objects/oops.c /home/tuna/myfolde/oops.c
```

Comment: Symbolic link is more like a shortcut. If you move the target file, then you need to recreate.

Comment: by default the link will be created in the current directory. So what you propose in the answer is not OP's problem.

Comment: The symbolic link still opens an empty file in myfolder folder

Comment: OK. Check for the content, permission of the file. If the link is dead then it would open a empty file.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If so could you please post the reply on what went wrong?